# How to pass a c# window(form) handle to a VB6 project or form?

Tags: c#, vb6

We have an application where we launch a VB modal dialog from a c# form on a button click. Even though the VB dialog is a modal window we are able to go back to C# dialog on click and then the application hangs.

Looks like the VB6 form does not have a parent and hence the issue. So we decided to pass the form handle from c# to VB and make our c# dialog as a parent to the VB dialog. Any help or a sample code would be really appreciated.

Once we click search on our c# dialog, we call this:

```
gPMSearch.Search();
```

The Search class is in VB:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Load the search form
    Set Form = New frmMain
    Load Form
End Sub
```

The form is loaded as below:

```
Me.Show vbModal
```

Comment: Please show us the code opening the modal dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Once we click search on our c# dialog we call this gPMSearch.Search(); The Search class is in VB Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'Load the search form
    Set Form = New frmMain
    Load Form

Comment: Once we click search on our c# dialog we call this 
gPMSearch.Search(); 

The Search class is in VB which eventually invokes the form.

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'Load the search form
    Set Form = New frmMain
    Load Form


The form is loaded as below

Me.Show vbModal

Comment: Don't use `Me.Show`; Instead call `Form.ShowDialog()` or `Form.ShowDialog(Me)`

Comment: @Guruprasad I've edited your question to include the code in your comment.

Comment: Great. I'll implemented this and get back.

Comment: @Guruprasad This is _your_ code, from your comment above. I just added it to your question to make it readable.

Comment: on VB I already have Me.Show vbModal but I don't think it's getting the parent. Is there any way I can send the form handle from c# to VB and make that as a parent for the vb form.

Answer (score 0):

Ownership of a window is set at window creation. Help says it can't be changed.

> **Owned Windows**
>   An overlapped or pop-up window can be owned by another overlapped or pop-up window. Being owned places several constraints on a window.
>
> An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order. 
>   The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is destroyed. 
>   An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized.
>
> Only an overlapped or pop-up window can be an owner window; a child window cannot be an owner window. An application creates an owned window by specifying the owner's window handle as the hwndParent parameter of CreateWindowEx when it creates a window with the WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_POPUP style. The hwndParent parameter must identify an overlapped or pop-up window. If hwndParent identifies a child window, the system assigns ownership to the top-level parent window of the child window. After creating an owned window, an application cannot transfer ownership of the window to another window.
>
> Dialog boxes and message boxes are owned windows by default. An application specifies the owner window when calling a function that creates a dialog box or message box.
>
> An application can use the GetWindow function with the GW_OWNER flag to retrieve a handle to a window's owner.

Are these in process or out of process VB6. Can't you call the VB6 form (rather than a sub) from C#

Anyway you'll need to write stupid code that simulates the behaviour you want. Monitoring their Z order and changing it as required.

So I'd put a timer in C# every 50ms. If test if C# is the active window, if so makes the VB6 active.

Comment: I can't call it directly from c#. I used setParent to set c# form as parent to the vb form. I need to pass the parent here Me.Show vbModal, ParentForm. But All I have here is handle and not the form object. How do I get the form object?

Comment: I don't think that .NET WinForms (C#) are compatible to VB6 forms anyway.

Comment: It is not a parent/child relationship you want. The edit control window is a child of notepad's main window. It has clipping and certain message processing. Owner/owned the windows have nothing to do with each other. This is seen in the print dialog in Notepad. As I said you'll have to simulate it.

Answer (score -1):

The point is to call `ShowDialog`, not just `Show`.

```
'Assuming that `MyModalDialogForm` is a c# object
Dim modalDialog = New MyModalDialogForm()
modalDialog.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Passing `Me` as the owner also ensures that the modal dialog stays on top of the other form.

If you need the result:

```
Dim modalDialog = New MyModalDialogForm()
If modalDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.Ok Then
    ...
End If
```

However; if the dialog is opened by `gPMSearch.Search();` you cannot influence the behavior of the form in VB6. You will have modify the code of `gPMSearch.Search()` in C#.

Comment: Once we click search on our c# dialog we call this 
gPMSearch.Search(); 

The Search class is in VB which eventually invokes the form.

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'Load the search form
    Set Form = New frmMain
    Load Form


The form is loaded as below

Me.Show vbModal

Comment: Not sure how to split my code and comments in a structured manner like yours here. But I have posted both above.

Comment: If the form is a C# object, then it has a `ShowDialog` method.

Comment: on VB I already have Me.Show vbModal but I don't think it's getting the parent. Is there any way I can send the form handle from c# to VB and make that as a parent for the vb form